# Get Value from Closed, Protected Workbook (Excel VBA, Excel4Macro)

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to retrieve a value from any range of my choosing from a closed *and* protected workbook (without opening the workbook).

My apologies to anyone who believes this to be a repeated question, but I have done my due diligence in searching the other answers, and from what I've seen nobody seems to have a solution that fits this problem.

So far I have had no issues in getting a value from a closed (but not protected) workbook by using `ExecuteExcel4Macro()`, however, the workbooks that I am querying are all protected (with the same password).

I can use `Workbooks.Open("wb.xls", Password:="youllneverguessit")`
but this takes just a half second to complete and the screen blips while executing. This is certainly something I can work with if I have to, but using the ExecuteExcel4Macro is *instant*.

When I use `ExecuteExcel4Macro()` to get a value from a closed *and* protected workbook, Excel prompts me for the password, as seen here:

[image]

I searched in vain on how to unprotect a closed workbook, and the Excel4Macro function that I am using, DEREF(), does not have a parameter whereby I can provide the password.

Ideally, I would like to have a function that just needs a few parameters: the workbook path, workbook name (if required), range (which could be either A1/R1C1 or a named range), and the password authentication. Honestly, the parameters aren't important, I just need to be able to provide the password authentication programatically.

This is what I have currently:

**1) Use `ExecuteExcel4Macro()` to get the value:**

When getting a value from a closed and protected workbook using this function, the user must provide a password manually.

```
Function GetValue(FileName As String, _
                  FilePath As String, _
                  shtName As String, _
                  Rng As String) As Variant

    Dim rConvert As Range
    Dim pSht As Worksheet

'   Convert our Rng string variable to R1C1
    Set pSht = Workbooks("PERSONAL.XLSB").Sheets(1)
    Set rConvert = pSht.Range(Rng)
    Rng = rConvert.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

'   Add a backslash to the file path if the user did not
    If Right(FilePath, 1) <> "\" Then FilePath = FilePath & "\"

    GetValue = ExecuteExcel4Macro( _
        "DEREF('" & FilePath & "[" & FileName & "]" & Code & "'!" & rng & ")")

End Function
```

**2) Open the workbook, get the information, close the workbook:**

When getting a value from a closed and protected workbook using this function, the user does not have to do anything manually, but it takes a moment to execute.

```
    Function get_value(wb_path As String, _
                       sht as string, _
                       rng_name As String, _
                       pass As String) As Variant

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim Rng as Range

    Set Rng = Workbooks.Open(wb_path, Password:=pass).Sheets(sht).Range(rng_name)

    get_value = Rng.Value
    wb.Close False

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Function
```

Thank you in advance! I appreciate anyone's help on this, even if we don't ultimately find the answer.

Comment: You could write your own function to extract, call it whatever, say `dataextract(strFileName, strPassword, strWorkSheet, strRange) as variant` and use ADO passing the password in the connection stirng.

Comment: I can't imagine many options that won't cause a *slight* delay (the data has to be retrieved after all) but in the past I've always kept a hidden tab with a table refreshed from a data connection to the source file. Set to refresh on open.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, guys. I'm looking into the ADO solutions now.